# Setcap not found in Debian 9

Tags: debian, setcap

I'm using a installation scripts that needs `setcap` and it's not found. What package contains it? `libcap2` is already installed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Searching for `setcap`

I believe `setcap` is contained in this package `libcap2-bin`. I found this by googling for "debian setcap" which led me to this man page:

- https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/libcap2-bin/setcap.8.en.html

The title of the man page tells you which package it resides in:

> / jessie / libcap2-bin / setcap(8)

Now that we "think" we know the package's name we can search for it:

- https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libcap2-bin

If you scroll down to the bottom of that page you'll see all the various architectures. Click the link for amd64:

- https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libcap2-bin/filelist

#### Found it

And there's `setcap`:

```
File list of package libcap2-bin in jessie of architecture amd64
/sbin/capsh
/sbin/getcap
/sbin/getpcaps
/sbin/setcap
/usr/share/doc/libcap2-bin/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libcap2-bin/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libcap2-bin/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/libcap2-bin/copyright
/usr/share/man/man1/capsh.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/getpcaps.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/capability.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/getcap.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/pam_cap.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/setcap.8.gz
```

Comment: @gabriel-a-zorrilla - if this resolves your issue please mark it as accepted so other's know your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 14):

Just do a search to see if a package has that command using

```
apt-file search setcap
```

if apt-file is not install first get it installed then re-issue above :

```
sudo apt install apt-file -y  && sudo apt-file update
apt-file search setcap
```

the entry you want appears as

> libcap2-bin: /sbin/setcap

now you know which package has it so install using

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
```

to see contents of an installed package issue

```
dpkg -L some-package
dpkg -L libcap2-bin
```

output includes these

```
/sbin/getcap
/sbin/setcap
```

so now you know how to install `setcap` and its get counterpart `getcap`